# Given a line segment, a line parallel to it, and a straightedge, divide the segment into $n$ equal segments

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, geometric-construction

> Given a line segment, a line parallel to it, and a straightedge, **how to divide the segment into $n$ equal segments?**

(With a straightedge, you are allowed only to draw straight lines. You are not allowed to mark off distances on the straightedge.)

Comment: You can't.  Not without a compass.  And if you have a compass ... you don't need the line parallel to it.  Where did you get this problem?  And what *exactly* does the question ask?

Comment: If you have a compass then.... hint.  You can extend the parallel line so that it in $n$ times as long and you can mark of $n$ tick marks on the long parallel line so that parallel line is divided evenly into $n$ equal parts (each part as long as the original line).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This took a lot of time to finish up. I hope it conveys the interesting nature of this problem. Although the problem is stated quite clearly, it seems to have caused some confusion in the comments and answers, so I will restate it differently:

> *Given a line segment and a line parallel to it, how can the line segment be partitioned into n equal segments **only** using a
> straightedge?*

---

Let's start with the $n=2$ case. Let the given line segment be **AB**, and let the given parallel line be defined with the points $\textbf{F}$ and $\textbf{E}$. Let's name the intersection point of the rays $\textbf{AF}$ and $\textbf{BD}$ as $\textbf{D}$. Let the intersection point of $\textbf{AE}$ and $\textbf{FB}$ be $\textbf{O}$. Let the intersection point of the ray $\mathbf{DO}$ with the line $\textbf{FE}$ be $\mathbf{H_{0}}$. Finally, let the point intersection of  the ray $\mathbf{DO}$ and $\textbf{AB}$ be $\mathbf{I_{1}}$. I created a sketch to work on in GeoGebra in the figure below.

### Theorem 1

In the following figure, point $\mathbf{I_{1}}$ is the midpoint of $\mathbf{AB}$, ie.:
\begin{equation}\label{theorem1}
\mathbf{AI_{1}}=\mathbf{I_{1}B}. 
\end{equation}

[image: geo1]

The proof of this theorem will use two well-known theorems; namely Thales' Theorem and Ceva's Theorem.
*Proof*.
Since $\textbf{AB} \parallel \textbf{FE}$, from Thales' Theorem:
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
    \frac{\textbf{AF}}{\textbf{FD}}=\frac{\textbf{BE}}{\textbf{ED}}$$

From Ceva's Theorem,
$$\frac{\textbf{AF}}{\textbf{FD}}\cdot\frac{\textbf{DE}}{\textbf{EB}}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{BI_{1}}}{\mathbf{I_{1}A}}=1$$

Substituting from Eq. $\ref{1}$,
$$\mathbf{AI_{1}}=\mathbf{I_{1}B}$$
we obtain the required result. $\blacksquare$

### Corollary 1.1

\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{2}
       \mathbf{FH_{0}}=\mathbf{H_{0}E}
\end{equation}
Proof.
This can be proved in several different ways. Since Eq.($\ref{1}$) and Eq.($\ref{2}$) were established before, by considering a homothety centered at $\textbf{D}$ it is clear that $\mathbf{FH_{0}}=\mathbf{H_{0}E}$. Alternatively, using the following similar triangles: $\bigtriangleup\mathbf{AI_{1}O} \sim \bigtriangleup\mathbf{EH_{0}O}$ and $\bigtriangleup\mathbf{BI_{1}O} \sim \bigtriangleup\mathbf{FH_{0}O}$, the corollary can be proven.
$\blacksquare$

[image]
Next, for the case $n=3$ (as in the Figure  above}, let's connect the points $\mathbf{I_{1}}$ and $\textbf{E}$ and name the intersection of $\mathbf{I_{1}E}$ and $\textbf{FB}$ as $\mathbf{X_{1}}$. Let the point intersection of  the ray $\mathbf{DX_{1}}$ and $\textbf{AB}$ be $\mathbf{I_{2}}$. Let the intersection point of the ray $\mathbf{DX_{1}}$ and line segment $\textbf{AE}$ be $\mathbf{Y_{1}}$. Let the intersection point of the ray $\mathbf{DX_{1}}$ with the line $\textbf{FE}$ be $\mathbf{H_{1}}$. Finally, let the intersection points of the line segment $\textbf{AB}$ and the rays $\mathbf{H_{1}O}$, $\mathbf{H_{1}Y_{1}}$ be points $\mathbf{W_{1}}$, $\mathbf{W_{2}}$ respectively. Notice that the ray $\mathbf{H_{1}Y_{1}}$ is contained by the ray $\mathbf{DX_{1}}$, and hence, $\mathbf{I_{2}}$ is coincident with $\mathbf{W_{2}}$. So, the point is labeled as  $\mathbf{I_{2}(W_{2})}$.
(Alternatively, we could've connected the points $\mathbf{I_{1}}$ and $\textbf{F}$ and name the intersection of $\mathbf{I_{1}F}$ and $\textbf{AE}$ as $\textbf{P}$. Then, we could obtain $\mathbf{W_{1}}$ by finding the intersection of ray $\textbf{DP}$ and $\textbf{AB}$. However, we will stick to the previous method as it is easier to generalize.)

### Theorem 2

---

In the figure above,
\begin{equation}\tag{3}\label{3}
\mathbf{AW_{1}}=\mathbf{W_{1}W_{2}}=\mathbf{W_{2}B}
\end{equation}

*Proof.*
Using Eq.(3) and similar triangles in Figure 2 , Theorem 2 can be proven.
\begin{equation}\tag{4}\label{4}
\bigtriangleup\mathbf{I_{1}X_{1}B} \sim \bigtriangleup\mathbf{EX_{1}F} \;and \bigtriangleup\mathbf{I_{1}X_{1}W_{2}} \sim \bigtriangleup\mathbf{EX_{1}H_{1}} \implies \frac{\mathbf{I_{1}B}}{\mathbf{2FH_{O}}}=\frac{\mathbf{I_{1}W_{2}}}{\mathbf{H_{1}E}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{5}\label{5}
\bigtriangleup\mathbf{AOW_{1}} \sim \bigtriangleup\mathbf{EOH_{1}} \;and \bigtriangleup\mathbf{W_{1}OI_{1}} \sim \bigtriangleup\mathbf{H_{1}OH_{0}} \implies
\frac{\mathbf{AW_{1}}}{\mathbf{H_{1}E}}=\frac{\mathbf{W_{1}I_{1}}}{\mathbf{H_{0}H_{1}}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{6}\label{6}
\bigtriangleup\mathbf{I_{1}OB} \sim \bigtriangleup\mathbf{H_{0}OF} \;and \bigtriangleup\mathbf{W_{1}OI_{1}} \sim \bigtriangleup\mathbf{H_{1}OH_{0}} \implies
\frac{\mathbf{I_{1}B}}{\mathbf{FH_{O}}}=\frac{\mathbf{W_{1}I_{1}}}{\mathbf{H_{0}H_{1}}}
\end{equation}

Combining Eq.(5),  Eq.(6), and Eq.(7), we get
$\mathbf{AW_{1}}=\mathbf{2{I_{1}W_{2}}}$.
By the symmetry of the figure, it is also true that,
$\mathbf{W_{2}B}=\mathbf{2{W_{1}I_{1}}}$.
Combining the two results with Eq. (1),
$\mathbf{AW_{1}}=\mathbf{W_{1}W_{2}}=\mathbf{W_{2}B}. \;  \blacksquare$

The proof for Theorem Theorem 2 using similar triangles can be extended to construct proofs for the rest of the theorems that will be deduced (for Theorem 3 and Theorem 4). Before trying to generalize, let's also analyze the case for $n=4$ in Figure below. Similar to what we did for the $n=3$ case let's connect the points $\mathbf{I_{2}}$ and $\textbf{E}$ and name the intersection of $\mathbf{I_{2}E}$ and $\textbf{FB}$ as $\mathbf{X_{2}}$. Let the point intersection of the ray $\mathbf{DX_{2}}$ and $\textbf{AE}$ be $\mathbf{Y_{2}}$. Let the intersection point of the ray $\mathbf{DX_{2}}$ with the line $\textbf{FE}$ be $\mathbf{H_{2}}$. Let the intersection points of the line segment $\textbf{AB}$ and the rays (purple) $\mathbf{H_{2}O}$, $\mathbf{H_{2}Y_{1}}$, and $\mathbf{H_{2}Y_{2}}$ be points $\mathbf{W_{1}}$, $\mathbf{W_{2}}$, $\mathbf{W_{3}}$ respectively. Note that $\mathbf{I_{1}}$ is coincident to $\mathbf{W_{2}}$ and $\mathbf{I_{3}}$ is coincident to $\mathbf{W_{3}}$.

[image]

### Theorem 3

---

In the figure above,
\begin{equation}\tag{7}\label{7}
\mathbf{AW_{1}}=\mathbf{W_{1}W_{2}}=\mathbf{W_{2}W_{3}}=\mathbf{W_{4}B}
\end{equation}

The same methodology can be applied repeatedly to obtain solutions for all values of ${\textit{n}}$. Let the intersection points of the line segment $\textbf{BF}$ with the rays $\mathbf{DH_{1}, DH_{2}, DH_{3},...,DH_{n-2}}$ be called as $\mathbf{X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, ..., X_{n-2}}$. Let the intersection points of the rays $\mathbf{DO, DX_{1}, DX_{2}, ..., DX_{n-2}}$ with the line $\textbf{FE}$ be $\mathbf{H_{0}, H_{1}, H_{2}, ..., H_{n-2}}$. Then, let's name the intersection points of the rays $\mathbf{DO, DX_{1}, DX_{2}, ..., DX_{n-2}}$ with the line segment $\textbf{AB}$ as $\mathbf{I_{1}, I_{2}, I_{3}, ..., I_{n-1}}$. Let's form the rays $\mathbf{H_{n-2}O, H_{n-2}Y_{1}, H_{n-2}Y_{2}, ... , H_{n-2}Y_{n-2}}$ and name the intersection points of these rays with $\textbf{AB}$ as $\mathbf{W_{1}, W_{2}, W_{3}, ..., W_{n-1}}$. Voil'a, the line segment $\textbf{AB}$ is partitioned into $\textit{n}$ equal segments. As a final note, $\forall \; (k+1)|n$, $\mathbf{I_{k}}$ is coincident to $\mathbf{W_{m}}$ for certain values of $\textbf{m}$.

### Theorem 4

---

In general,
\begin{equation}\tag{8}\label{8}
\mathbf{AW_{1}}=\mathbf{W_{1}W_{2}}=\mathbf{W_{2}W_{3}}=\mathbf{W_{3}W_{4}}=...=\mathbf{W_{n-1}B}
\end{equation}

Let's illustrate it with an example. Suppose, we are trying to divide $\textbf{AB}$ into six equal segments. Thus, in this case $n=6$, and we can use the general method we derived. Applying the method discussed above, the figure below can be obtained. Notice the labeling of the following points: $\mathbf{I_{1}(W_{3})}, \mathbf{I_{2}(W_{4})}, \mathbf{I_{5}(W_{5})}$. As stated above, this coincidence occurs because 2, 3, and 6 are factors of 6.

[image]

Comment: Wow [+1]!! That was amazing :). As an observation, the idea behind the cases $n=2^k$ is projective geometry (which makes sense, since you can only employ the straightedge) and the construction of the harmonic bundle $(A,B; P_{\infty}, I_1)\implies I_1$ is the midpoint of $AB$. I only had one *question*: What's the motivation behind the construction for the general case $n$? Once you gave the steps, it's easy to come up with a solution, but I don't see how the solution or any other observations should motivate the construction...

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Unfortunately, I can’t offer any intuition for my method, but I’ll try to explain. I was playing the game Euclidea (highly recommended) when I came across a problem asking for an only straightedge construction for the case $n=2$. It got me wondering whether it was possible for all $n$. After getting the $n=2$ case, I knew I could repeat the same argument to generalize for $n=2^k$, but the other values of $n$ seemed challenging. After scribbling on a paper for hours, I managed to come up with construction for $n=3$. I was still curious whether it was possible for all $n$.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial Answer**

Here's a solution for the case $n = 2$, which might provide you some inspiration for the more general case. The picture tells the whole story. The red line $PQ$ is the initial segment, the blue line is the parallel one. We pick points $A$ and $B$ on the blue line at random. We join each of $A$ and $B$ to each end of the initial segment. The lines $PA$ and $QB$ intersect at the magenta point; the lines $PB$ and $QA$ intersect at the blue point, and joining the blue and magenta points and taking the intersection with the original line $PQ$ gives us the red point, which is the midpoint of $PQ$.

Note that I *did* need to assume I could pick two distinct points on a given line; I'm not certain that this is allowed in straightedge-only constructions.

Clearly this solution generalizes to handle all cases where $n$ is a power of $2$ (just apply recursively to sub-lines), but I don't see how to do $n = 3$; presumably once that's clear, the rest is downwind sailing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint.  Assuming you are allowed a compass...

It might seem hard to divide the given line $n$ times but you can take the parallel line; extend it $n$ times to get a parallel line that is $n$ times longer than it was originally and you have successfully divided *that* big new line in $n$ equal parts.

Is there any way to take those $n$ parts an the parallel line to make $n$ equal parts of the original line?

What do you know about parallel lines, and equal angles, and similar triangles?

Time to brainstorm....

......

[image]