# using diagonals of the a trapezoid inside a triangle you can find the midpoint of the bases

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

In the following triangle, AB is parallel to DE. F is an intersection point of the segments BD, AE and CG. Is it true that AG = GB?
[image]

Comment: This problem comes up very frequently in different contexts of Euclidean/Projective geometry. Ex.:  [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4005996/804253)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Ceva Theorem: $${AG\over GB}\cdot {BE\over EC}\cdot {CD\over DA}=1$$ and Thales theorem: $${CD\over DA} = {EC\over BE} $$ and thus a conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

In the following, I have incorrectly assumed D and E are the midpoints of CA and CB respectively. Please jump right to the section labeled  as "CORRECTED version".

We can play withit using areas. The respective regions are labelled as shown.
[image]

(1) + (2) = (3) = (6) = (8)+ (7)

∴  (1) + (2) + (3) = (6) + (8)+ (7) = x, say

$\dfrac {x + (4)}{x +(5)} = \dfrac {(4)}{(5)}$

This gives (4) = (5) and the required result follows

---

CORRECTED version

Let C(F)G cut DE at H. Suppose that DH : HE = p : q.

[image]

Then, (1) by similar triangles, AG = kp and GB = kq for some non-zero constant k; (2) by triangles with the same altitude, [FDH] = hp and [FEH] = hq for some non-zero constant h.

Let [AFG] = x and [BFG] = y. Then, by considering areas of similar objects, $x = hq \times (\dfrac {kp}{q})^2$ and $y = hp \times (\dfrac {kq}{p})^2$.

Therefore, $\dfrac {x}{y} = … = (\dfrac {p}{q})^3$

Since, by considering area of triangles with the same altitude, $\dfrac {x}{y} = \dfrac {kp}{kq}$

From $(\dfrac {p}{q})^3 = \dfrac {kp}{kq}$, we have $p = q$ after rejecting the negative quantities.

Comment: why (1) + (2) = (3)?

Comment: This is because the two triangles have the same altitude and their bases are equal. hence they are equal in area.

Comment: Do you mean AD=DC?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus The diagram misled me to wrongly assume that D, E are the midpoints. If I cannot fix it, this post will be deleted shortly.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Sorry for the wrongly-assumed answer. Please see the CORRECT version.